# JS : endDate issue in viewmode "months" using bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Using the following dates `"2013,01,01"` and `"2015,09,28"` and `startdate` and `enddate`,
bootstrap datepicker works perfectly in a daily viewmode,
but switching to monthly viewmode, the month of the endDate and the previous one (here September and August) are not clickable, regardless all the different date values and formats i have tried. (first/last day of month,

Some code :

```
                var params_datepicker = {
                    language : "fr-FR",
                    clearBtn : true,
                    autoclose : true,
                    todayHighlight : true,
                    format : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    startDate : new Date(limitesdates.min), // 2013,01,01
                    endDate : new Date(limitesdates.max)  // 2015,09,28
                };
```

Any idea?

Comment: Which Bootstrap datepicker? can you show some code?

Comment: Please give us some more info on which bootstrap-datepicker you run, which version of the lib and some sample code that fails

Comment: @Ofiris :  v1.6.0 (git repository : [link](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) )

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code and it works with 1.6.0-alpha - https://jsfiddle.net/vjz6e5mw/. Be aware that `new Date(2013,01,01)` equals to Fri Feb 01 2013 00:00:00. So january will not be selectable (same for enddate 09 = october)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day chasing this bug (thanks to acrobat, the fiddle made me figuring out where the bug was located), i finally found the bug.
My bootstrap-datepicker.min.js file was not up to date, (~ 2 weeks). 
I noticed that as i joined the last bootstrap-datepicker.js to my project : the issue vanished as soon as i joined the latest files.
Have a nice day. ;)